# Como saber a quantidade de filmes por categorias das que possuem menos de 50 filmes?

Tags: sql, count

Tenho uma tabela de filmes com:
  -id_filme,
  -nome_filme,
  -id_categoria;
E outra de categoria com:
  id_categoria,
  nome_categoria;

como faço selecionar apenas a categoria e a quantidade de filmes das que tiverem menos de 50 filmes?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Tente fazer assim (caso esteja a utilizar SQL Server):

```
SELECT NOME_CATEGORIA, COUNT(ID_FILME) AS QTD 
FROM TABELA1 (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN TABELA2 (NOLOCK) ON
 TABELA1.ID_CATEGORIA = TABELA2.IDCATEGORIA
GROUP BY NOME_CATEGORIA
HAVING COUNT(ID_FILME) < 50
```

O "HAVING" é conhecido também como o "WHERE" do "GROUP BY".

*Postar o código poderá ajudar a solucionar sua questão mais rapidamente.*